# How should asp.net custom errors work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, custom-error-pages

I have implemented custom errors in my asp.net mvc application by following [this article](http://www.genericerror.com/blog/2009/01/27/ASPNetMVCCustomErrorPages.aspx). What I have noticed is that if I go to http://www.mysite.com/some-non-existent-controller-and-action I get my 404 error page as expected. However, looking at what happens with firebug, I see that I get a 302 Found response for the non-existent page, which then redirects to my custom error page which then returns with a 404 (and displays the custom error page). Is this right? I don't think the 302 that is first returned is very good especially from an SEO perspective, and that maybe I need to think again about how I have implemented this.

Comment: I never noticed this before, but I just confirmed that this happens on my MVC2 app with custom errors implemented.

Comment: Looking into some of the solutions, I do not believe you can use those and customErrors at the same time. I would like to figure out how to make the customErrors return a direct 404 without the 302. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best guide(i think) for handling 404s can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc/2577095#2577095). Basically there are multiple ways in which 404s can happen:

1. No route exists - matched by the catch all rule.
2. Matched route but not found a controller - for rules with dynamic controller names - `{controller}/{action}/{parameter}` rule.
3. Found route, but didn't find action - handled through `HandleUnknownAction` override.
4. Found route and action but couldn't convert parameters - matched by the catch all rule.

The linked answer basically sets up a controller that can be executed from any point in the code without rewriting the URL - which is what you want.

In addition, you should also think about handling unhandled exceptions and bad URLs (like the ones containing unsafe characters like angle brackets). I that particular case you **have to** rewrite the URL, otherwise you can't render the response at all. These particular requests are kind of tricky, i blogged about that [here](http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/2010/06/18/handling-404-unhandled-and-unsafe-url-errors-in-asp-net-mvc-application/).

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I will take a proper look and feedback

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the advice down towards the bottom of the page adding a "catch-all" route that maps to your "NotFound" action:

```
routes.MapRoute("Catch All", "{*path}",
    new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" });
```

If you make this the very last route you add, any "unknown" URLs will map directly to your "NotFound" action on the `ErrorController` and you can just return the "not found" view directly from there, no redirects required.